# window jumping after ajax load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a blog w/ infinite scroll http://www.hvac-hacks.com , i also ajax load comments on each post.  The top post doesnt jump after the comments ajax load, but as you go further down, and as you continue to load more pages, the jumping just gets worse and worse.  I read that I just need to use `return false` and put that in every function and it still jumps.

EDIT:
There is a block of JS that should move it proper, but not sure what this is about.

```
if ( location.hash ){
                        $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: $( location.hash ).offset().top
                        });
                        $( location.hash ).addClass( 'inline-comments-highlight' );
                    }
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

    // $('#default_add_comment_form textarea').textareaAutoExpand();

    /**
     * Default ajax setup
     */
    $.ajaxSetup({
        type: "POST",
        url: _inline_comments.ajaxurl,
        dataType: "html"
    });


    window.inline_comments_ajax_load_template = function( params, my_global ) {

        var my_global;
        var request_in_process = false;

        params.action = "inline_comments_load_template";

        $.ajax({
            data: params,
            global: my_global,
            success: function( msg ){
                $( params.target_div ).fadeIn().html( msg );
                request_in_process = false;
                if (typeof params.callback === "function") {
                    params.callback();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Submit new comment, note comments are loaded via ajax
     */
     $( document ).on('submit','.default-add-comment-form',function( e ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css('opacity','0.5');
        var full_id = this.id;
        var explode_post_id = full_id.split("-",2);
        var post_id = explode_post_id[1];
        console.log ("posting a comment for post id: #"+post_id);

        data = {
            action: "inline_comments_add_comment",
            post_id: post_id,
            user_name: $('#inline_comments_user_name_'+post_id).val(),
            user_email: $('#inline_comments_user_email_'+post_id).val(),
            user_url: $('#inline_comments_user_url_'+post_id).val(),
            comment: $( '#comment_'+post_id ).val(),
            security: $('#inline_comments_nonce_'+post_id).val()
        };
        console.log ("data stream(var array data):");
        console.log ("* action: "+data.action);
        console.log ("* post_id: "+data.post_id);
        console.log ("* user_name: "+data.user_name);
        console.log ("* user_url: "+data.user_url);
        console.log ("* comment: "+data.comment);
        console.log ("* security: "+data.security);
        console.log ("---end");

        console.log ("target_div: "+"#inline_comments_ajax_target_"+post_id);
        console.log ("template: " + $( '#inline_comments_ajax_handle' ).attr( 'data-template' ));
        console.log ("post_id: " + post_id);
        console.log ("security: " + $( '#inline_comments_nonce_'+post_id ).val());
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            global: false,
            success: function( msg ){
                inline_comments_ajax_load_template({
                    "target_div": "#inline_comments_ajax_target_"+post_id,
                    "template": $( '#inline_comments_ajax_handle' ).attr( 'data-template' ),
                    "post_id": post_id,
                    "security": $( 'inline_comments_nonce_' +post_id).val()
                } );
                $('textarea').val('');
                $this.css('opacity','1');
                return false;
            },
            fail: function(){
                console.log("ajax failed");
            },
                always: function(){
                console.log(msg);
            }
        });

    });

    /**
     * Allow Comment form to be submitted when the user
     * presses the "enter" key.
     */
    $(document).on('keypress', '.default-add-comment-form',function (e) {
      if (e.which == 13) {
        console.log ("Enter Key Pressed - Submitting form");
        console.log (this);
        console.log ($(this));
        $(this).submit();
        return false;
      }
    });

    $(window).on('scroll.inline-ajax-comments', function (e) {
        var elem = isScrolledIntoView('.inline-comments-ajax-start')

        if (elem)
        {
            var $elem = jQuery(String(elem));

            if ($elem.hasClass('inline-comments-loaded')) {
                //console.log($elem+'already loaded');
                return false;
                } 
            else {
                $elem.addClass('inline-comments-loaded');
                console.log('Load comments for '+$elem);
                console.log('post id: '+$elem.attr('data-id'));
                inline_comments_ajax_load($elem.attr('data-id'))
                }

        }

    });



    window.inline_comments_ajax_load = function(post_id){
        //console.log("load comments for post "+post_id+"...");
        if ( $( '#inline_comments_ajax_handle_'+post_id ).length ) {
            $( '.inline-comments-loading-icon').show();

            data = {
                "action": "inline_comments_load_template",
                "target_div": '#inline_comments_ajax_target_'+post_id,
                "template": $( '#inline_comments_ajax_handle').attr( 'data-template' ),
                "post_id": post_id,
                "security": $('#inline_comments_nonce_'+post_id).val()
            };
            console.log("loading comments for post: "+data.post_id);
            $.ajax({
                data: data,
                success: function( msg ){
                    $( '.inline-comments-loading-icon').fadeOut();
                    $( "#inline_comments_ajax_target_"+post_id).fadeIn().html( msg ); // Give a smooth fade in effect
                    if ( location.hash ){
                        $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: $( location.hash ).offset().top
                        });
                        $( location.hash ).addClass( 'inline-comments-highlight' );
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

            $( document ).on('click', '.inline-comments-time-handle', function( e ){
                $( '.inline-comments-content' ).removeClass('inline-comments-highlight')
                comment_id = '#comment-' + $( this ).attr('data-comment_id');
                $( comment_id ).addClass('inline-comments-highlight');
            });
        }
        return false;
    }

    $( document ).on('click','.inline-comments-more-handle', function( e ){
        event.preventDefault();
        //Get the post id
        var full_id = this.id;
        var explode_post_id = full_id.split("_",2);
        var post_id = explode_post_id[1];
        console.log (post_id);

        if ( $( this ).hasClass('inline-comments-more-open_'+post_id) ){
                $( 'a', this ).html( _inline_comments.custom_more.more );
                 $('#comment_'+post_id).animate({height: '32'},250);
                 } else {
            $( 'a', this ).html( _inline_comments.custom_more.less );
             $('#comment_'+post_id).animate({height: '100'},250);
        }
            $( this ).toggleClass('inline-comments-more-open_'+post_id);
            $('#inline-comments-more-container_'+post_id).toggle();
    });


    /*
    window.inline-comments-more-toggle = function(post_id){

        if ( $( this ).hasClass('inline-comments-more-open_'+post_id) ){
            $( 'a', this ).html('●●●');
            $('#comment').css('height', '32');
        } else {
            $( 'a', this ).html('↑↑↑');
            $('#comment').css('height', '150');
        }
        $( this ).toggleClass('inline-comments-more-open_'+post_id);
        $('#inline-comments-more-container_'+post_id).toggle();
    }
    */

    window.isScrolledIntoView = function(elem) {
        var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
        var elemInView = false;
        $( elem ).each(function() {
            $this = $(this);

            elemTop = $this.offset().top;
            elemBottom = elemTop + $this.height();
            if ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop)) {

                elemInView = $this.attr('data-id');
            }
        });
        //if (elemInView) console.log(elemInView+ " is in view!!!!");
        if (elemInView) return elem+'[data-id="'+elemInView+'"]';

    }


});
```

PHP

```
<?php

/**
 * Our comments form template, the comments loop is loaded via html from inline_comments_load_template()
 */
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) die( 'You cannot access this template file directly' );

?>
<?php
    $name = 'Name&#8230';
    $email = 'Email&#8230';
    $website = 'Website&#8230';
    $user_email = null;
    $user_website = null;
    $user_name = null;
    $keep_open = get_option('keep_open');
    $custom_more = get_option('custom_more');
    $more = inline_comments_options( 'custom_more', empty( $custom_more ) ? 'default' : $custom_more );

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ){
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $user_name = $current_user->display_name;
        $user_email = $current_user->user_email;
        $user_website = $current_user->user_url;
    }
?>

<noscript>JavaScript is required to load the comments.</noscript>
<div class ="inline-comments-ajax-start" data-id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" ></div>
<div class="inline-comments-container" id="inline-comments-container_<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" name="comments" >
    <div id="inline_comments_ajax_handle_<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" id="inline_comments_ajax_handle" class="inline_comments_ajax_handle last-child" data-post_id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
    <div id="inline_comments_ajax_target_<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" style="display: none;" ></div>
    <div class="inline-comments-loading-icon">Loading Comments&#8230;</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="inline_comments_nonce" value="<?php print wp_create_nonce('inline_comments_nonce'); ?>" id="inline_comments_nonce" />
    <?php if ( get_option('comment_registration') != 1 || is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
        <div class="inline-comments-content inline-comments-content-comment-fields">
            <div class="inline-comments-p">
                <form action="javascript://" method="POST" id="default_add_comment_form-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" class="default-add-comment-form">
                    <input type="hidden" name="inline_comments_nonce_<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" value="<?php print wp_create_nonce('inline_comments_nonce_'.$post->ID); ?>" id="inline_comments_nonce_<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" />
                    <?php inline_comments_profile_pic(); ?>
                    <textarea placeholder="Press enter to submit comment&#8230;" tabindex="4" id="comment_<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" name="comment" id="inline-comments-textarea" class="inline-comments-auto-expand submit-on-enter"></textarea>
                    <span id ="inline-comments-more-handle_<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" class="inline-comments-more-handle"><a href="#"><?php echo $more['more']; ?></a></span>
                    <div id = "inline-comments-more-container_<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" class="inline-comments-more-container" <?php if ( $user_email != null && isset( $keep_open ) && $keep_open != "on" ) : ?>style="display: none;"<?php endif; ?>>
                        <div id="inline-comments-allowed-tags-container_<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" class="inline-comments-allowed-tags-container">
                            Allowed <abbr title="HyperText Markup Language">HTML</abbr> tags and attributes:
                            <code>&lt;a href="" title=""&gt; &lt;blockquote&gt; &lt;code&gt; &lt;em&gt; &lt;strong&gt;</code>
                        </div>
                        <div class="inline-comments-field"><input type="text" tabindex="5" name="user_name" class="inline_comments_user_name" id="inline_comments_user_name_<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" placeholder="<?php print $name; ?>" value="<?php print $user_name; ?>"  /></div>
                        <div class="inline-comments-field"><input type="email" required tabindex="5" name="user_email" class="inline_comments_user_email" id="inline_comments_user_email_<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" placeholder="<?php print $email; ?>" value="<?php print $user_email; ?>"  /></div>
                        <div class="inline-comments-field"><input type="url" required tabindex="6" name="user_url" class="inline_comments_user_url" id="inline_comments_user_url_<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" placeholder="<?php print $website; ?>" value="<?php print $user_website; ?>" /></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php else : ?>
        <div class="callout-container">
            <p>Please <?php echo wp_register('','', false); ?> or <a href="<?php print wp_login_url(); ?>" class="inline-comments-login-handle">Login</a> to leave Comments</p>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<script id="inline-comments-script-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" class="inline-comments-script" >
/*
    //console.log ('<?php echo $post->ID; ?>' + 'has loaded...');
    var tid_<?php echo $post->ID; ?> = setInterval( function () {
    if ( document.readyState !== 'complete' ) return;
        clearInterval( tid_<?php echo $post->ID; ?> );
        //console.log ('running script for post id: <?php echo $post->ID; ?>');
        inline_comments_ajax_load(<?php echo $post->ID; ?>)
    }, 100 );
    */
</script>
```

Comment: This is the only one that needed a return false as far as a page jump is concerned: `$( document ).on('click', '.inline-comments-time-handle',` if it's still jumping, then that isn't your problem. Likely it's a css problem due to the fact that when you add more content to a page, the scrollHeight changes and content will sometimes change position on the page depending on where you insert it.

Comment: First step is to narrow it down to the specific line that causes the scroll.

Comment: The jumping is due to the comments, which load later. As you scroll down past unloaded comments, the jump occurs as the comments load.

Comment: DDS is correct.  I need to add a `margin-top` offset for every comment loaded.

Comment: `if ( location.hash )` should be compensating, no?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user @DDS...

The problem was a css issue, primarily the "loading" div was using `.fadeOut` which causes display:none - instead I used `.fadeTo` and now it is working great!

Changed:
`$( '.inline-comments-loading-icon').fadeOut();` to `$( '.inline-comments-loading-icon').fadeTo( 1000, 0 );`